# How to integrate a smaller map into a larger map

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, google-maps, mapbox

I am trying to integrate an area which I have created as it's own map onto a larger map.

I would like to show the location of this organization on a map with it's surrounding areas. When I zoom in onto the area of the organization, the details/layout of the smaller map(layout through the organization) should become visible.

With the map I have created, it is places on an image with outlines of certain buildings and stores (it's a mall), I am able to calculate distances among other operations. I just need to figure out how to implement *zooming in to reveal my smaller map* on this larger map. This map will be displayed on a website as well as integrated on a native mobile application, such as an android app, however implementation on the webpage is more important.

Comment: @d.datul1990 Nope, I ditched using the Google Maps to provide this functionality to focus on displaying more detail on the mall's map itself. The deadline for my project is nearing but if I have time I'll simply provide an embedded map of the mall on some page.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API provides map tiles at various  [zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions) for map type imagery. Most roadmap imagery is available from zoom levels 0 to 18. The MaxZoomService object provides a simple interface for discovering the maximum zoom level at a given location.

Accessing the MaxZoomService is asynchronous, since the Google Maps API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the request. This callback method should process the result.

To initiate a request to the MaxZoomService, simply call getMaxZoomAtLatLng(), passing the LatLng of the location and a callback function to execute upon completion of the  [request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#view_mode).

Here are related SO ticket which discuss Maps API zoom range: [google map API zoom range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356724/google-map-api-zoom-range) / [Using setZoom() after using fitBounds() with Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523023/using-setzoom-after-using-fitbounds-with-google-maps-api-v3)