# change radius by zoom level

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I wish to calculate radius in meters or km according to the zoom level.

I've found this formula - which gives me the roughly calculated meters per pixel:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/hDRO4oHVSeM

Also, these links assisted me in understanding what I was trying to accomplish exactly:
[google map API zoom range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356724/google-map-api-zoom-range)
[How to get center of map for v2 android maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904505/how-to-get-center-of-map-for-v2-android-maps)

and this is the implementation:

```
double calculateScale(float zoomLevel, LatLng centerPos){
    double meters_per_pixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(centerPos.latitude * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoomLevel);

    return meters_per_pixel;
}
```

and this is how I listen to the zoom level changing:

```
        _map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            Log.d(Consts.TAGS.FRAG_MAIN_MAP,"Current Zoom : " + _map.getCameraPosition().zoom);
            Log.d(Consts.TAGS.FRAG_MAIN_MAP,"Center Lat : " + _map.getCameraPosition().target.latitude +
                    ", Center Long : " + _map.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
        }}
```

Now, whenever the user changes zoom level, I wish to determine what is the maximum radius that can be displayed within the map view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next snippet:

```
_map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        Log.d(Consts.TAGS.FRAG_MAIN_MAP,"Current Zoom : " + _map.getCameraPosition().zoom);
        Log.d(Consts.TAGS.FRAG_MAIN_MAP,"Center Lat : " + _map.getCameraPosition().target.latitude +
                ", Center Long : " + _map.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);

        float zoom = _map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        LatLng position = _map.getCameraPosition().target;
        double maxRadius = calculateScale(zoom, position) * mapViewDiagonal() / 2;
    }
}

private mapViewDiagonal() {
    return Math.sqrt(_map.getWidth() * _map.getWidth() + _map.getHeight() * _map.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: This answer showed me how to calculate the max radius in a way that suits my use case (I've used the map container layout instead of _map).

Comment: Sorry, I use too much details. Main point was to get half of diagonal of view and it will be maxRadius. :) Glad you got this point.